# Do people still celebrate "Frankfurt Purim"?

Tags: purim, chagim-holidays, adar, yekke

The people of Frankfurt, historically, have celebrated a mini-Purim ("פורים קטן") on 20 Adar, to commemorate their salvation from threat of extinction (see [this article](http://www.lambdapublishers.com/year/english/adar_stories.htm) for a summary of the events).

Someone [mentioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/is-someone-killed-by-force-called-kiddush-hashem/48986?noredirect=1#comment130237_48986) to me that he didn't believe that it was celebrated anymore; now I wonder if this is correct.

**Do the Jews of Frankfurt** (current residents, or descendants of Jews who lived in Frankfurt) **still celebrate Frankfurt Purim?** Do they read the *megillah* that was written for the event? With food and drink? Or do they not celebrate it at all?

*Related question -- does any other Jewish group, besides for the Frankfurt Jews, celebrate this miracle?*

Comment: It seems many other groups celebrate a variety of miracles http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12450-purims-special

Comment: @eliyahu-g Cool, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4):

[This link](http://www.torahmedia.com/search/fileinfo.php?sid=k0383hteqp05bna&cid=w036a8el3p98sm7&directlink=34927) is of a Chazan in Khal Adas Yeshurun Jerusalem singing a Birchas Nisim in honor of Purim Frankfurt. This is from 5767/2007.

Comment: No, the recording is of him singing birkas she'oso nissim on regular Purim in accordance with the niggun of Frankfurt. Frankfurt Purim is not really practiced anywhere today (including Washington Heights, which was founded by people from Frankfurt).

Answer (score 3):

An old frankfurter once told me that the only vestige of Purim Frankfurt during his youth in the prewar period was the would sing Adon Olom to the military band tune which accompanied vinz to the gallows.